# Cannot find module 'assetmanager'

Tags: node.js, npm, mean-stack

I'm trying to run the MEAN stack on windows. I've installed all the pre-requisites (I think) but when I try to start the server via the gulp command I get the error:

Error: Cannot find module 'assetmanager'.

IMAGE:

[image]

I have tried running npm install assetmanager which run fine but I still get this error.

This is my first time trying to run node on a machine (I should have used a linux box) so go easy on me as I am learning :-).

Any and all help appreciated.

David

Comment: No one with any ideas :-( can't get past this.

Comment: did you get any erros while running npm install?

Comment: nope none at all :-(

Comment: did you check the node_modules folder?

Comment: Just checked the folder and it is there and the assetmanager is there with the files in it. Do you know where this module.js file the error is talking about is located I have a few of these files kicking about but am unsure as to which one the error is about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem on Linux Mint 17.2.

**The failing way**: This was my first project that I'd generated and I don't think I had all the dependencies installed before I ran the init command (g++ was missing).

I tried the `npm install assetmanager` command as you did and then install worked. Running gulp after this, it got further but this time I was missing `mongoose`. I installed that then it couldn't find `.../config/env/all` so I sylinked the default.js config. Then running `gulp` again, `errorhandler` was missing. I figured it shouldn't be this hard so...

**The working way**: I deleted that failure of a project and `init`'d a new one and it worked. Unfortunately I'm not sure if the `init` didn't work the first time but I missed the error/warning or something else caused it. All I can recommend is try creating another project and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I guess the mean project is in a bit of a state of flux. Every now and then you should get the latest and greatest from github.